# Idiomatically evaluate true if Option contains specific value

Tags: scala

I want to write a method that returns `true` if an `Option[Int]` contains a specific value and false otherwise. What is the idiomatic way of doing this?

```
var trueIf5(intOption: Option[Int]): Boolean {
  intOption match {
    case Some(i) => i == 5
    case None => false
  }
}
```

This above solution clearly works, but the Scala docs label this approach as [less-idiomatic](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option).

Is there some way I can do the same thing using `map`, `filter`, or something else?

I got this far, but it only changes the problem to "Return true if Option contains `true`", which is effectively the same as "Return true if Option contains `5`".

```
var trueIf5(intOption: Option[Int]): Boolean {
  intOption.map(i => i == 5).???
}
```

Comment: `exists` is the right answer, but your `???` above would be `.getOrElse(false)`. Then you recognize that you have `.map(f).getOrElse(z)` and call that `.fold(z)(f)`. Then you realize that (on `Option`) `.fold(false)` is `.exists` and `.fold(true)` is `.forall`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you're testing whether it contains a value:

```
scala> Some(42) contains 42
res0: Boolean = true
```

Don't neglect your `-Xlint`:

```
scala> Option(42).contains("")
res0: Boolean = false

scala> :replay -Xlint
Replaying: Option(42).contains("")
<console>:12: warning: a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error.
       Option(42).contains("")
                           ^
res0: Boolean = false
```

Those built-in warnings aren't as effective with universal equality:

```
scala> Option(42).exists("" == _)    // no warning
res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: In the end, I'm now using both of these solutions. I wish I could mark them both as an answer. You have my upvote, but @sjrd gets the green check because of his timing. You don't need the extra rep anyway ;)

Comment: What I don't know is why these methods are invisible in the scaladoc.

Comment: If you see an `Option` as a container, this method is much more idiomatic than exists, IMHO. Nice one!

Answer (score 12):

```
intOption.exists(_ == 5)
```

[The doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option@exists%28p:A=%3EBoolean%29:Boolean)

Comment: Viewing the `Option[T]` as a sequence of 0 or 1 `T` is the correct way.

Answer (score 3):

Why has no one suggested:

```
intOption == Some(5)
```

Comment: Usually you try to avoid an extra allocation, tho' the other answers incur an allocation at least for some cases.